# 'missing-syscalls' error during kernel compilation

Tags: linux

These are the steps I am doing to compile the linux source on my machine : 
1. Copy the config file from /boot to /usr/src/kernels/2.6.29.4-167.fc11.i586/ directory
2. make oldconfig
3. make

Step 3 fails with the following error : make[1]: *** No rule to make target `missing-syscalls'. Stop.

Compiling on a x86 box. Any suggestions ? Please feel free to close this question if it does not belong here.

Comment: Add an update saying its just when doing make oldconfig when this error occurs, not when using vanila .config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you ensure kernel-headers and kernel-devel are installed?

eg: yum install kernel-headers kernel-devel

These are the steps I did on FC11 with vanilla kernel linux-2.6.30.4

```
# -- decompress kernel source into /usr/src --
# cd /usr/src/linux-2.6.30.4
# cp /boot/config-2.6.29.6-217.2.fc11.x86_64 ./.config
# make clean
# make oldconfig
# choose 2 (Bzip2) kernel
# Hit enter and accepted the defaults for all the answers - You may want to do different
# make bzImage
# make modules
```

Comment: The vanilla kernel compiles fine as suggested in the steps. There were 2 more steps after this : 
make install_modules 
make install 

The above 2 steps setup the entry in menu.lst in /boot/grub/ and install the compile kernel image in the right place.

Comment: Besides this, I really don't have the answer to the real question itself. Perhaps someone can answer the reason behind 'missing-syscalls' error.

Comment: Yeah, i did not include the last two steps as we wanted the kernel to compile successfully so did not do the install_modules or the copy of bzImage to /boot directory